# SQL server -Union conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, and I want to get the results of both of these queries. Note that `machine_output` is a view I created :

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblcertified.employeenumber, 
                tblcertified.machinenumber 
FROM   tblcertified 
       INNER JOIN machine_output 
               ON tblcertified.machinenumber = machine_output.machinenumber 
UNION 
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, tblperiod.fromdate) AS fDate, 
       tblscheduled.employeenumber 
FROM   tblperiod 
       INNER JOIN tblscheduled 
               ON tblperiod.number = tblscheduled.number 
WHERE  tblperiod.fromdate BETWEEN Dateadd(m, -3, Getdate()) AND Getdate()
```

When running the above, I get the following **error**:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I also get this error when I **drop** the `convert` statement.

Comment: Even if you can convert it, does it have the same type as Employeenumber ( in the first query)? you know that in a UNION both queries should have same type and same number of columns in their result sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first column in the first subquery is called `EmployeeNumber`.

Your first column in the second table is being converted to `Date`.

I don't think you want a `union`, but you are familiar with joins.  Your `select` lists needs to match for a `union`.

If you want to fix this, change the first select to something like:

```
select distinct cast(NULL as date) as fDate, tblcertified.employeenumber, tblcertified.machinenumber
```

and the second select to something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, tblperiod.fromdate) AS fDate, 
       tblscheduled.employeenumber , NULL
```

As a `join`, your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (DATE, tblperiod.fromdate) AS fDate, tblcertified.employeenumber, 
                tblcertified.machinenumber
FROM   tblcertified 
       INNER JOIN machine_output 
               ON tblcertified.machinenumber = machine_output.machinenumber 
       INNER JOIN tblscheduled 
               on tblscheduled.employeenumber = tblcertified.employeenumber
       INNER JOIN tblperiod
               ON tblperiod.number = tblscheduled.number 
WHERE  tblperiod.fromdate BETWEEN Dateadd(m, -3, Getdate()) AND Getdate() ;
```

This is a bit of guess as to what you want (you have no sample data to make it clear).  But, you can do all the joins in one query and pull out the columns you need.

Comment: Oh so I'm really not after union. I want to get the results in one query not 2 columns. How do I do that?